# voron 2.4 mainsail kiauh error install crowsnest (solved problem)

Tags: raspberry-pi

This error appears if someone is installing a full raspberry pi os for whatever reason.
So just `run sudo apt install rpicam-apps-lite` and after that try again

the problem solved, this is for everyone who experience this problem.

[image of the error at install crowsnest from kiauh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk7EB.png)

https://github.com/dw-0/kiauh

```
Installing with camera-streamer ...
Installing dependencies ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.39.2-1.1).
bsdutils is already the newest version (1:2.38.1-5+b1).
findutils is already the newest version (4.9.0-4).
v4l-utils is already the newest version (1.22.1-5+b2).
curl is already the newest version (7.88.1-10+deb12u5).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.9).
libjpeg-dev is already the newest version (1:2.1.5-2).
pkg-config is already the newest version (1.8.1-1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rpicam-apps : Conflicts: rpicam-apps-lite but 1.4.3-1 is to be installed
 rpicam-apps-lite : Conflicts: rpicam-apps but 1.4.2-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Install dependencies ... [FAILED]
Something went wrong!
Please copy the latest output, head over to
    https://discord.gg/mainsail
and open a ticket in #supportforum...
make: *** [Makefile:19: install] Error 1
Something went wrong! Please try again...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if someone is installing a full Raspberry PI OS for whatever reason. So just run:

```
sudo apt install rpicam-apps-lite
```

…and after that try again.